# WCF Data Services configuration

Tags: wcf-data-services

I've found out to get error details from WCF Data Service, i should set `config.UseVerboseErrors = true` in `InitializeService`. (I'm new to WCF Data Services)

It seems settings within `config` class should be hardcoded, and i think it's not a good idea to hardcode settings like `UseVerboseErrors`. Is there any section in web.config for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there's no counterpart in the .config files for this. On the other hand, it's pretty easy to code this yourself. Instead of assigning a constant value in your InitializeService, simply assign a value extracted from the config file.

Comment: Thank you @Vitek, nice & easy solution :)